# Google Sheets: ArrayFormula Conditional Calculations across Rows

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, array-formulas

struggling to find a way to perform a calculation taking a look at a previous row in an Arrayformula. Perhaps it isn't possible the way I'm attempting to do it?

Sample Columns:

| Time/Date Conversion | In/Out | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| February 9, 2022 11:57PM | In |  |
| February 10, 2022 07:47AM | Out |  |
| February 10, 2022 11:28PM | In |  |
| February 11, 2022 08:40AM | Out |  |

I'm able to use an arrayformula to determine if the row shows "Out"; and I know how to calculate the time difference between the date/times; but I can't seem to do the two in combo.

Resulting hours would appear in the Hours column when the In/Out row shows "Out."

BTW - Yes, this would be much easier if the In and the Out times were in the same row, but the software that auto-adds these to the spreadsheet doesn't do that (and doesn't even add them as a real date and time, so I had to use some funky regex to accomplish that. Good times!)

Thanks for your ideas, as always!

CTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just couldn't get the solution provided by Mike to work, as fascinating as it was; as such, I pieced together the following solution:

A hidden column which I labeled "Pull Forward," with the formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(If(C3:C<>"",B2:B999,""))
```

This brought the previous time into the same row for easy calculations, in the hours column:

```
=Arrayformula(If(C2:C="Out",B2:B-D2:D,""))
```

Not the sexiest answer, but it's reliably getting the job done.

Thanks,

CTO

Answer (score 0):

### solution:

Try in C1 (format duration)

```
={"Hours";ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B="In",,if(A2:A="",,mmult(-1*(ROW(A2:A)=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)+1))+1*(ROW(A2:A)=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A))),if(A2:A="",0,A2:A)))))}
```

[image]

### reference:

[mmult](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292)

### explanation:

mmult between a matrix of -1/0/1 as follows and the data

```
=arrayformula(-1*(ROW(A2:A9)=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A9)+1))+1*(ROW(A2:A9)=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A9))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm.. love the ingenuity here, and it's beyond my current level of knowledge/understanding, so a great learning opportunity. 

Unfortunately, however, this results in an error for me, @Mike Steelson, "the resulting array was too large."

Comment: I assume your comment is about the formula in my explanation? Reduce the number of rows if not used and let me know if it works! However, does the solution work as is? The second formula is just for explanation and is not used as is in your actual sheet.

Comment: Second formula (only for explanation) : `=arrayformula(-1*(ROW(A2:A9)=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A9)+1))+1*(ROW(A2:A9)=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A9))))` and probably delete all columns added previously by google.